# Different meanings of brackets in Python

Tags: python, brackets

I am curious, what do the 3 different brackets mean in Python programming? Not sure if I'm correct about this, but please correct me if I'm wrong:

- `[]` - Normally used for dictionaries, list items
- `()` - Used to identify params
- `{}` - I have no idea what this does...

Or if these brackets can be used for other purposes, any advice is welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### Square brackets: `[]`

Lists and indexing/lookup/slicing

- Lists: `[]`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `[i**2 for i in range(5)]`
- Indexing: `'abc'[0]` → `'a'`
- Lookup: `{0: 10}[0]` → `10`
- Slicing: `'abc'[:2]` → `'ab'`

### Parentheses: `()` (AKA "round brackets")

Tuples, order of operations, generator expressions, function calls and other syntax.

- Tuples: `()`, `(1, 2, 3)`

  - Although tuples can be created without parentheses: `t = 1, 2` → `(1, 2)`
- Order of operations: `(n-1)**2`
- Generator expressions: `(i**2 for i in range(5))`
- Function or method calls: `print()`, `int()`, `range(5)`, `'1 2'.split(' ')`

  - with a generator expression: `sum(i**2 for i in range(5))`

### Curly braces: `{}`

Dictionaries and sets, as well as in string formatting

- Dicts: `{}`, `{0: 10}`, `{i: i**2 for i in range(5)}`
- Sets: `{0}`, `{i**2 for i in range(5)}`

  - Except the empty set: `set()`
- In string formatting to indicate replacement fields:

  - F-strings: `f'{foobar}'`
  - Format strings: `'{}'.format(foobar)`

### Regular expressions

All of these brackets are also used in regex. Basically, `[]` are used for character classes, `()` for grouping, and `{}` for repetition. For details, see [The Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075).

### Angle brackets: `<>`

Used when representing certain objects like functions, classes, and class instances if the class doesn't override `__repr__()`, for example:

```
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> zip
<class 'zip'>
>>> zip()
<zip object at 0x7f95df5a7340>
```

(Note that these aren't proper Unicode angle brackets, like `⟨⟩`, but repurposed less-than and greater-than signs.)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Maltysen's answer and for future readers: you can define the `()` and `[]` operators in a class, by defining the methods:

- [`__call__(self[, args...])`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) for `()`
- [`__getitem__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for `[]`

An example is [`numpy.mgrid[...]`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c23bd98de665733dd090636f38b6aacf9f99450b/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L148). In this way you can define it on your custom-made objects for any purpose you like.

Answer (score 2):

() parentheses are used for order of operations, or order of evaluation, and are referred to as *tuples*.
[] brackets are used for lists. List contents can be changed, unlike *tuple* content.
{} are used to define a dictionary in a "list" called a *literal.*

Comment: *"parentheses ... are referred to as tuples"* -- Totally incorrect. Parentheses have a much broader purpose than just for tuples (e.g. calls like `print()`), and tuples can be defined without parentheses (e.g. `t = 1, 2`).

Comment: *'{} are used to define a dictionary in a "list" called a literal.'* -- No, [literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#literals) are immutable by definition, therefore not including dicts, which are mutable. You might be thinking of [displays](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries), which includes "lists" and comprehensions.

Answer (score -2):

Tuple is immutable(order inside it can't be changed once created),and are enclosed in parenthesis,separated by ("," or ','). Tuple is used to store multiple items in a single variable.

**Example:**

```py
thistupple("apple","banana","mango")
print(thistupple)
```

**Output:**

```py
('apple', 'banana', 'cherry')
```